# Is it okey to call events from Repository Pattern in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, events, repository-pattern

I have repository pattern where i create model. I would like to call event every time when model is created, should i do it from controller or from repository ? If i do it in repository pattern will i break single responsibility principle ?
Here is my code example

```
class FriendshipRepository implements IFriendshipStorageRepository
{
    public function create(User $user, User $follower): Friendship
    {
        $friendship = Friendship::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'follower_id' => $follower->id
        ]);

        event(new FriendshipCreatedEvent($friendship));

        return $friendship;
    }

    public function destroy(User $user, User $userToUnfollow)
    {
        $friendship = $user->getFriendship($userToUnfollow);

        $friendship->delete();

        event(new FriendshipDeletedEvent($friendship));
    }
}
```

Or should i make one more layer between controller and repository ?
New layer would use repository and call events, but the controller would only call that new layer.

Comment: Laravel Eloquent models already fires a lot of events, I dont think you need to fire the same events from the repository, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

Comment: @dparoli Great ! I really did not know about this which will help me a lot. But still, where should i fire events if they are not fired automatically such as eloquent events ? Should it be repository or controller?

Comment: You should look for observers in the same docs I linked, and read the @Shizzen83 answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use Services for such use cases. Your controller could call a `NewFriendshipService`.

This service will implement a workflow, like this:

- Create relationship in database (using your repository)
- Send notification to the new friends
- Calculate new friendship recommendations ("you may also know this person")
- ...

The service can then act as kind of "middleware" between controller and repository. Good practice here is, that services just implement the workflow, but no business logic directly.

Comment: I think this is exactly what i need. I will have better look at it, but as far as i see it is something like middle layer where i can but my flow... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, if you could provide me some good documentation and examples it would be really great.

Comment: https://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services
I  hope this one explains the idea better.
Here's another resource...although it questions the concepts of repositories as a whole, but I guess it adds some more insights: https://medium.com/@sergiumneagu/laravel-why-youve-been-using-the-repository-pattern-the-wrong-way-952aedf1989b

Answer (score 3):

In order to respect the single responsibility principle, you may use an observer class [Eloquent Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers).

Its methods are "automatically" called by Laravel when you perform an Eloquent operation (such as `created` and `deleted` about your use-case)

Comment: I might call some events that can't be called from eloquent operation. This was only my current example, but i need to fire many events. That is why i am in doubt, if it should be called from repository or controller

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO